# How To Convert Offline files downloaded from Lynda.com

Tags: vlc-media-player, mp4

As a premium member you can download course video files from Lynda.com. I have downloaded files for the courses that I have completed. The files in reside in the respective folder and have a .Lynda extension. These files open only through Lynda Desktop App. I tried opening them using VLC but they don't. Is there any way to convert these files?

Comment: Could you run one of the files through [trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) and tell us what it says?

Comment: Here is what we are getting after running through trid

TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.24 - (C) 2003-16 By M.Pontello

* Error: found no file(s) to analyze!

Comment: Same issue i am facing with PluralSight offline videos, all pluralsight videos have extension .psv, i don't know how to decrypt them into .mp4 or other extensions which can be run easily either in Vlc player or windows media player.

any clue, please help.

Answer (score 13):

Currently, the answer's **Yes!**

There's [a fairly new GitHub repository](https://github.com/h4ck-rOOt/Lynda-Decryptor) that provides a tool for the decryption of such files. The files themselves are AES-encrypted (which is decrypted using the [Rijndael decryption module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx)) - so it isn't really surprising that VLC can't open them...

These are the available options for the tool:

```
Usage (Directory): LyndaDecryptor /D PATH_TO_FOLDER [OPTIONS]
Usage (File):      LyndaDecryptor /F ENCRYPTED_FILE DECRYPTED_FILE [OPTIONS]

Flags:
        /D      Source files are located in a folder.
        /F      Source and Destination file are specified.
        /DB     Search for Database or specify the location on your system.
        /RM     Removes all files after decryption is complete.
        /OUT    Specifies an output directory instead of using default directory.
```

For example (using some common setting for Windows):

```
LyndaDecryptor /D "E:\PATH_TO_COURSES\ldc_dl_courses\COURSE_NUM" /DB "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\lynda.com\Lynda.com Desktop App\db.sqlite" /OUT "E:\OUTPUT_PATH"
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to run this GitHub project? There are literally ZERO instructions on their project. Their readme file leads to an image logo. I can see an SLN file but no instructions. On googling SLN files we get to know that it's the file structure for "Visual Studio". I don't want to go about learning Visual Studio just to run this project.

Comment: @Mugen The repository provides you with the _source code_ of the tool. VS is just one of the compilers you can use to turn _source_ into _executables_, should you decide to do it yourself. However, this is not required, because the author also provided so-called "precompiled binaries" for Windows (`.exe` files). Check out the "[Releases](https://github.com/h4ck-rOOt/Lynda-Decryptor/releases)" section of the repository.

Comment: Seems like things have change. Videos are now saved in `.ldcw`extension and this program are not able to decrypt them .
Any ideas ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi One of the first things I'd do is open an issue in GitHub with details of this problem. Perhaps the developer could solve it if he knew about it. (The tool seems to be getting updates, which leaves room for optimism.)

Comment: How can we use it on mac?

Answer (score 0):

I think the common media players and converters may not process the specific file with .Lynda extension. The only method comes in my mind is to use a video recorder freeware like Camstudio to record the live stream on Lynda and then you can convert the recorded videos.